# How to submit a form by clicking a link javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

currently I'm trying to make it so that when the user clicks a link it submits the corresponding form via javascript. I used document.getElementById("id").submit() as a basis on how to send the form so my code should act similar to it in my understanding.

Here's the code:

```
function run(clickedLink){
clickedLink.id.submit();       //I did it like this since document.getElementById just gets the form id and since link and form have similar id's I thought it would send
}

<form id = 'formId'>
<a href = '#' id = 'formId' onclick = run(this)>Link</a>
</form>
```

I tried going with name = 'formId' too but it still doesn't run as I wanted it too.

Note: doing this since this code iterates dynamically and the id gets updated i.e. formID1, formID2...

Better ways to implement this are welcome too

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with same id in an HTML document, it's invalid...

Comment: Did you try this `onclick="this.parentNode.submit();"` ? And please, please don't use links for something that's not a link. I'm bored of links that cannot be opened in new tab by a middle click. Put some CSS on a submit button instead.

Comment: I tried this suggestion and it seems to work out perfectly...and yeah I'll switch to buttons. I based it off the previous design hence why I made it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your function as follows

```
function run(clickedLink){
  clickedLink.parentNode.submit(); // parentNode refers to the form element
}
```

Comment: wow that's awesome been at this for a few hours now and it seems to work unlike my most current attempt which seems to skip rows

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use same id on the same page for more than one element. This is against HTML and DOM specifications https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really .

You can change it to `class` if you want to reuse or you can change the id itself of other element. Also links are not recommended to submit the form. Their job is to navigate

Comment: I see I'll keep that in mind hopefully I didn't make a lot of my other forms like this...that will be a lot of rewriting to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].v.value='Link1';
document.forms[0].submit();">Link 1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One Basic thing:

-`ID's` are used to Uniquely Describe The Element in `DOM` Hierarchy. Please Don't Repeat it. (it is really bad)

Now to the answer:

```
function run(x){
var y=findParentForm(x); /* if Id's aren't Unique */
// If iD's are Unique :- var y=document.getElementById("formId");
y.submit();
}

function findParentForm(elem){ 
/* 
This function will find exact parent form 
even if link or elem is inside <div> or other complex DOM structure
This will Only return the parent <form> of that elemnt 
*/ 
var parent = elem.parentNode; 
if(parent && parent.tagName != 'FORM'){
parent = findParentForm(parent);
}
return parent;
}

<form id='formId' action="Server Side Script" method="GET/POST">
<a href='#' id='formId' onclick ="run(this);">Link</a> <!-- change id of link -->
</form>
```